# This with other selector

Tags: jquery, html, this

I'm trying to display number of selected checkbox in each div, but don't know how to select `span`.

This `$("input[@type=checkbox]:checked",this).length` works fine, I've put it in alert and number is correct, but I don't know how to select `#skills div h3 span` for each div.

html

```
<td id="skills" colspan="2">
  <div id="skills_0">
    <h3>IT<span></span></h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name=".." id=".." val=".." /> <label for="..">..</label>
    ...<!-- more inputs -->
  </div>
  ...<!-- more divs -->
</td>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#skills div').each( function () {
        $("h3 span",this).html($("input[@type=checkbox]:checked",this).length);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
/* $(this).find('span').html($("input[@type=checkbox]:checked",this).length); */
```

The new update code:

```
$(this).find("h3 span").html($("input[@type=checkbox]:checked",this).length);
```

demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/ongisnade/VQutV/3/

Comment: Do you have a demo on jsfiddle.net to make me more clearly know the error.